# Error:(3, 32) java: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr

I'm working on a project to create a compiler of a mini java language, I use intellij
I downloaded the jar file and add the CLASSPATH and add the plugins on the IDE.
during the generation of ANTLR recognizer on the class baseListener() and visitor() the import of org.antlr.v4.runtime. can't be apply and i don't know why and whene i tryed to build project module this errors are finded :
Build completed with 100 errors and 0 warnings in 7 s 951 ms
Error:(3, 32) java: package org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa does not exist
Error:(12, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Parser
...
Any help please

Comment: Make sure antlr runtime jar is on the classpath

Comment: it's on the classpath

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It looks like you are missing antlr jars in the module dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Comment: it's okay thanks i'd just miss the antlr jars in the module

Answer (score 0):

Did you have installed the ANTLR?

If not, follow this commands to install:

```sh
$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ sudo curl -O https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.8-complete.jar
```

Then, set the classpath to know the antlr library

```sh
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.8-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
```

If you already install antlr, just setting classpath maybe works.